# Can you tell me why my code for turning an array to a number, adding one, and returning an array only works on some datasets?

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I'm trying to solve the following Leetcode problem:

> You are given a large integer represented as an integer array digits,
> where each digits[i] is the ith digit of the integer. The digits are
> ordered from most significant to least significant in left-to-right
> order. The large integer does not contain any leading 0's.
>
> Increment the large integer by one and return the resulting array of
> digits.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: `digits = [1,2,3]`   Output: `[1,2,4]`   Explanation: The array
> represents the integer `123`. Incrementing by one gives `123 + 1 = 124`. Thus, the result should be `[1,2,4]`.

Here's my code :

```
var plusOne = function(digits) {
    
    let newDigit = digits.join('')
    if (newDigit.length > 15) {
        let digitLength = newDigit.length
        let secondHalf = newDigit.slice(digitLength - 15, digitLength)
        secondHalf = parseInt(secondHalf) + 1
        secondHalf = Array.from(String(secondHalf), Number)
        digits.splice(digitLength - 15, 15)
        return digits.concat(secondHalf)
        
        
    
    }
    let Digit = parseInt(newDigit) + 1
    const answer = Array.from(String(Digit), Number)
    return answer        
};
```

Works for many data sets. Get's the following error on the following set. Why :(

[image]

Comment: Use a debugger, it's your best ally.

Comment: Tangential, but this code seems to be EXTREMELY over-engineered for the constraints posed by the problem itself - you’ll begin running into problems where you’re casting arbitrarily half of the digits in a given number value as an integer where those figures have leading zeroes in the now-halved string. Somewhat separately, have you considered that many of the integers resulting from your calls to `parseInt` would likely (far) exceed JavaScript’s `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` constant and lead to unexpected behavior? Can you elaborate as to why you haven’t elected to use something like `BigInt`?

Comment: @HelenGeorge Please post output (including error messages) as text, not a link to a painting of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `parseInt(secondHalf)`, you're effectively dropping any leading zeros in that string, and as a result those zeros don't get included in the final array. The input digits are guaranteed not to have any leading zeros, but that doesn't mean that there won't be any leading zeros if you slice the string in the middle.

Also, even fixing that, what about input arrays that are longer than 30 characters?

Consider using a BigInt instead, it'll be a lot easier.

```js
const plusOne = function(digits) {
  const bigInt = BigInt(digits.join('')) + 1n;
  return [...String(bigInt)].map(Number);
}

console.log(plusOne(
  '590840235570031372488506112'.split('').map(Number)
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] PlusOne(int[] nums) {
         string initialValue = "";

        foreach(int i in nums) {
            initialValue += i.ToString();
        }

        long value = long.Parse(initialValue) + 1;
        
        

        int[]  resValue = new int[value.ToString().Length];
        
        for(int i=0; i< value.ToString().Length; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("Value is " + value.ToString()[i]);
            resValue[i] = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(value.ToString()[i]);
         
        }
        
        // return value.ToString().Split();
        // return Array.ConvertAll(value.ToString().Split(), p => Int32.Parse(p) );
        // return (from person in value.ToString().Split() select Int32.Parse(person)).ToArray();
        // return value.ToString().Select(c => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c));
        return resValue;
    }
```